# How to ignore previous Sammy "get" route if newer is started

Tags: javascript, sammy.js

I have simple sammy routing declared like:

```
$.sammy("#main", function () {

   this.get(/\#\/(.*)/, function (context) {

       context.load(url, { json: true }).then(function (result) {
          // some result custom processing

          return result.Html;

       }).swap();

   }).run('#/');

});
```

Everything is working very well, except one small issue. If I'm clicking on my links very fast, all requests are started. However they sometimes finishing in different order than started - which is normal because some are longer then others.

But because they are finishing in different order, the final result on screen in content from swap is different than current selected page.

Is there any way to cancel/ignore previous request (which is still asynchronously processing) if newer one is already processed?